# Diferencia entre db.collection.ensureIndex() y db.collection.createIndex() en mongodb

Tags: mongodb

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre crear un índice mediante el comando `ensureIndex()` y el comando `createIndex()` de MongoDB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A partir de la versión `3.0` de MongoDB, `ensureIndex()` ha sido deprecado en favor de `createIndex()` y es considerado como un alias de este último:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, no existe una diferencia si estás usando la versión `3.0`, si usas `ensureIndex()` en realidad estarías llamando a `createIndex()` implícitamente.

En la versión `2.6` de [`ensureIndex()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) lo que hacía era crear el índice en el **campo** especificado solo si no existía anteriormente.

La version `3.0` de [`createIndex()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) crea los índices en las **colecciones**.

Comment: Usa la palabra correcta en vez de decir deprecado; Es como decir "responsivo" en vez de "adaptativo".